# armadillo library c++ solve the linear equation that is inconsistent

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm using armadillo library I try to use this code to solve a System of a linear equation I input a case that should be inconsistent but it output a solve for the equation ! 
I try this

```
x+y=3,
4 x + 4 y = 10
```

this the code

```
mat A(2,2);
vec B(2);
A << 1 << 1 << endr
  << 4 << 4 << endr;
B << 3 << endr
  << 10 << endr;
vec Ans;
Ans = solve(A,B);
cout << Ans << endl;
```

from the documntation it says that if a solution not found it will throws and excption

> If no solution is found:
>   X = solve(A,B) resets X and throws a std::runtime_error exception
>       solve(X,A,B) resets X and returns a bool set to false (exception is not thrown)

so what should I do so when I solve inconsistent it should throws and exception or return false or anything what is the right way to do that

Thanks in advance

Comment: Might be helpful to show us the solution it produced.

Comment: You have a soution mathematically speaking. It is simply not unique. So there should be no exception by documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default armadillo tries to find approximate solution for [singular matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) `A`:

```
warning: solve(): system seems singular; attempting approx solution
   1.2647
   1.2647
```

You should disable this behavior with `solve_opts::no_approx` option:

```
Ans = solve(A,B,solve_opts::no_approx);
```

See documentation for [solve()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#solve).